# Is this a valid SVG path?

Tags: svg, w3c

I've run into a problem rendering the following SVG path with various svg libraries:

```
<path d="M19.35 10.04c-.68-3.45-3.71-6.04-7.35-6.04-2.89 0-5.4 1.64-6.65 4.04-3.01.32-5.35 2.87-5.35 5.96 0 3.31 2.69 6 6 6h13c2.76 0 5-2.24 5-5 0-2.64-2.05-4.78-4.65-4.96zm-2.35 2.96l-5 5-5-5h3v-4h4v4h3z"/>
```

specifically, you can see something odd about this block:

```
4.04-3.01.32-5.35
```

this fixes it:

```
4.04-3.01+0.32-5.35
```

... as does this:

```
4.04-3.01 0.32-5.35
```

My reading of the SVG spec suggests the original path is invalid, but since the icon comes right out of Google's material design icons (https://github.com/google/material-design-icons) - and there's many similar "errors", I'm a little suspect of my reading of the BNF.

Can anyone offer a second opinion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4.04-3.01.32-5.35 is valid. The SVG [path specification grammar](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataBNF) says that we're processing this

> curveto-argument comma-wsp? curveto-argument-sequence

The ? after comma-wsp means 0 or 1 of those. In this case we've 0.

Tracing through the BNF we end up in the part that's about parsing numbers prior to any exponentiation character i.e.

> digit-sequence? "." digit-sequence.

Once we've seen one full stop we can't see any more unless we see an exponent and so the second full stop must be part of something else i.e. the next number.

So the above character sequence corresponds to the values: 4.04 -3.01 .32 -5.35

Comment: I was just about to post the same link. Here's the relevant part: *Similarly, for the string "M 0.6.5", the first coordinate of the "moveto" consumes the characters "0.6" and stops upon encountering the second decimal point because the production of a "coordinate" only allows one decimal point. The result is that the first coordinate will be "0.6" and the second coordinate will be ".5".*

Comment: @squeamishossifrage hit the nail on the head. It's the fractional-constant: digit-sequence? "." digit-sequence that the parsers must not be following correctly. If the answer above could be edited to reflect that part of the spec in detail, I'll mark it as correct. In the meantime, off to file a bug against librsvg...